# WCF Faulted State?

Tags: wcf

I am currently developing WCF Publish Subscribe Service. For the first I don't know how many minutes, it is able to work properly after the client has been subscribed to the server and it is able to receive the post that the publisher publishes.

After like 10 minutes or so, the client suddenly stop responding to those publishing and when I attempt to unsubscribe from the service, there is an error of a faulted state.

I am currently using WSDualHttpBindings.

Anyone know why does this happens?

Comment: A faulted state usually occurs because the service has hit an error which wasn't properly caught and handled on the server, and thus the communication link between client and server is "faulted".

Comment: Sounds like you may have hit a timeout - what are your timeout settings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Manage to solve the issue by adding the following code to my binding

```
bindings.receiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Timeouts are there for a reason. What happens if your underlying service goes down? You're never going to know that it has gone down. If you want to maintain an open connection, it's best to handle the faulted event and reconnect. If you're only doing the odd operation, create your proxy when you need it, and close it when you're done with it...